# Showing PermissionState error while adding @capacitor/camera plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to upload photos from the gallery but using @capacitor/core, it will open camera only. And, showing this error after installing @capacitor/camera.

```
[ng] ERROR in node_modules/@capacitor/camera/dist/esm/definitions.d.ts:1:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.
[ng] 1 import type { PermissionState } from '@capacitor/core';
[ng]               ~
[ng] node_modules/@capacitor/camera/dist/esm/definitions.d.ts:1:38 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 1 import type { PermissionState } from '@capacitor/core';
[ng]                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] node_modules/@capacitor/camera/dist/esm/index.d.ts:1:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.
[ng] 1 import type { CameraPlugin } from './definitions';
[ng]               ~
[ng] node_modules/@capacitor/camera/dist/esm/index.d.ts:1:35 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
[ng] 1 import type { CameraPlugin } from './definitions';
[ng]                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is my `package.json` file.

```
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^1.3.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.0.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.0.1",
```

Comment: it doesnt look like you have the latest packages installed

Answer (score 0):

Its a typescript error so first upgrade typescipt to latest version.
run

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

and then check version

```
tsc -v
```

copy the version and search typescript in package.json and paste the version.
now do

```
npm install
```